# Python - FizzBuzz - How to Get Number and String to Both Print

Tags: python, printing, range

I have this bit of Python code:

```
    for num in range(1,21):
    string = ""
    if num % 3 == 0:
        string = string + "Fizz"
    if num % 5 == 0:
        string = string + "Buzz"
    if num % 5 != 0 and num % 3 != 0:
        string = string + str(num)
    print(string)
```

And I'm wondering how to make it so that it prints the number + "Fizz" for multiples of three.

I.e. we should see

```
1
2
3 Fizz
4
Buzz
6 Fizz
7
8
9 Fizz
Buzz
11
12 Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz
16
17
18 Fizz
19
Buzz
```

Instead of what's currently printing:

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz
16
17
Fizz
19
Buzz
```

I tried

```
if num % 3 == 0:
        string = string.extend("Fizz")
```

But that returned `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extend'`. Same for `.append`.

Do you have any suggestions for how to print the number in the range AND the word / string "Fizz" after it for multiples of 3  in the range in Python?

Thank you!

Comment: Use string formatting: `string = '%d %s' % (num, "Fizz")`. See: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

`string = string + "Fizz"`

into :

```
string = str(num)+ " " + "Fizz"
```

Alternatively, as suggested by @ArpitSvt:

```
string = "{} Fizz".format(num)
```

Note : `str` function explicitly casting `int` num to `str` type.

Comment: Not quite - this will print "3Fizz" if `num == 3`. You need a space somewhere

Comment: You should always prefer string formatting over string concatenation. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/304447

Comment: Thank you - this worked. Can you please explain what `str(num)` is doing exactly? What's the technical difference between `string` and `string(num)`?

Comment: It is typecasting `num` which of integer type to string type.